# Is is possible to detect triple-tap?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I found [PointerInputScope.detectTapGestures](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/gestures), which allow us to provide callbacks for single and double taps, but I would like a triple tap as well.

Should I copy the [source code for `detectTapGestures`](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/compose.foundation/foundation/1.0.0-source/androidx/compose/foundation/gestures/TapGestureDetector.kt.html) and add another `if` block under `// Second tap down detected` to check for the third tap? Is there a better way?

Comment: If you don't need to have both triple and other gestures from this function, I'd remove unnecessary code from so it'll only detect triple taps, but generally that's the right way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

**You can**, if you save the last two click times and you can compare this times. For example if at 08:55:40,08:55:50 and after that in the next click you should get 3rd click time and compare these 3 if there is a small differences then you can say yes its a triple click or no its not a triple click.